# Javascript function is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, sms

I want to count typed character bytes for sms application. If ASCII is typed it counts 1 byte and for non ASCII it counts 2bytes. If the total character byte is more than 80bytes, the script should alert('You have reached over 80bytes') and after this it should cut from the end until it is less than 80bytes. However, cutBylen() function seems not working in this script. It just alerts but does not cut the string. Can someone tell me where the problem is? Thank you very much.

```
                <script>
                    function countBytes( str ) {
                        var count = 0;
                        for ( var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ) {
                            var onechar = str.charAt( i );
                            if ( str.charCodeAt( i ) >= 128 ) {
                                count += 2;
                            } else if ( onechar != '\r' ) {
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                        return count;
                    }
                </script>
                <script>
                    function cutByLen( str, byteLen ) {
                        var tmpStr = str;
                        while (countBytes( tmpStr ) > byteLen) {
                            var len = tmpStr.length;
                            tmpStr = tmpStr.substr( 0, len - 1 );
                        }
                        return tmpStr;
                    }
                </script>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {

                        $("#smstext1").keyup(function(){
                            var text = $(this).val();
                            var byteLen = countBytes(text);
                            var len = text.length;

                            if (byteLen >80){
                                alert('You have reached over 80bytes');

                                var tmpStr = cutByLen( text, byteLen );

                                $(this).val(tmpStr);    

                            }


                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
var tmpStr = cutByLen( text, byteLen );
```

where `byteLen` is the length of the text so it cuts the string if it's longer than itself, which obviously does nothing. What you probably meant was

```
var tmpStr = cutByLen( text, 80 );
```

Comment: Perfect! It really worked. I got really frustrated during debugging and found nothing. I knew that it should be very simple. Thank you again, dude :).